# Amazon Linux PHP Mbstring

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install mbstring module in amazon ec2 server this is the error i'm receiving

command run "sudo yum install php-mbstring"

```
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have googled and tried many options but nothing is defined for PHP 5.6

I have also enabled zend.multibyte in php.ini ( also verified it in phpinfo() )

Comment: Looks like you are trying to install a PHP5.6 module into a PHP5.3 Do AMAZON really run PHP5.3?

Comment: i'm running sudo yum install php-mbstring what should i do ? 
php -v give me php 5.6.12

Comment: @RiggsFolly, no it's other way round.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Amazon Linux gives you a variety of choices. PHP 5.3 is no longer available in their repo, but it used to be.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have php5.6 installed, the correct command to add mbstring support is
`sudo yum install php56-mbstring`

Comment: Answers are expected to be instructional. Please, elaborate on why this command will work.

Comment: @AntonioPérez, I don't know why it was packaged this way. Happy to delete the answer on first downvote if it's wrong or violates any rules.

Comment: It's not that your answer should be deleted, it's that it could be improved if you could explain a bit of what it does different from the OPs command.
From [SO help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better*

Comment: I'd wish I could explain better. Anyone who knows how it works is more than welcome to amend the answer. I believe the help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer, it is just the way these libraries are packaged in the Yum repository. Not really anything that needs to be elaborated on.

Comment: @AlexBlex OMG thanks for the answer dude. Solved my issue and have accepted the answer :) i don't think this required better explanation than this it's php 5.6 so php56-mbstring what more is required to explain here :D